# How do I deiconify with a button when iconified for a JInternalFrame

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a JInternalFrame where it can iconify, deiconify, close, etc. This JInternalFrame is opened when a button is clicked. But if the frame has been opened and is iconified and the user clicks the button again, I don't want the frame to open again. So I was wondering how do you make an iconified frame to deiconified (so basically when the user clicks the button again it just deiconifies the frame).

I searched this up and I found for JFrames you can do:

```
frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
```

but this doesn't exist for internal frames. Does anybody know what I can do to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but this doesn't exist for internal frames.

`JInternalFrame` has methods like:

1. `setIcon(...)`
2. `setMaximum(...)`